# Output the object keys when the condition for object values is greater than 5

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value-store

```
var veg = {"mushroom": 30, "pepper": 60, "corn": 1, "carrot": 
2, "pumpkin": 4}
```

If the object value is greater than 5, then print all the keys from veg. I can't seem to figure out how to put the if statement condition within my code.

I got all the values and keys using for loop through the object.

```
function getKey(veg){
  var arr = [];
  for (var x of Object.keys(veg)){
    arr.push(x);
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(getKey(veg))

//----------------------------------------

function getVal(veg){
  var arr = [];
  for (var i of Object.values(veg)){
    arr.push(i);
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(getVal(veg))

// END GOAL

must return ["mushroom", "pepper"]
```

Comment: FYI, `Object.keys` and `Object.values` already return arrays. Iterating over arrays with `for...in` is almost always wrong. Your code produces arrays containing numbers.

Comment: Yes I totally forgot about that, Thank you. Gotta use of in the for loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using method **for in**

```js
var veg = {"mushrooms": 30, "peppers": 60, "meatballs": 1, "chicken": 
2, "olives": 4}
            
function getKey(veg){
  const arr = [],
  obj = Object.keys(veg);
  for (var x in obj){
    if(veg[obj[x]] > 5){
      arr.push(obj[x]);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(getKey(veg))
```

Using method **forEach**

```js
var veg = {"mushrooms": 30, "peppers": 60, "meatballs": 1, "chicken": 
2, "olives": 4}

function getKey(veg){
  const arr = [];
  Object.keys(veg).forEach(function(item){
    if(veg[item] > 5) arr.push(item);
  }); 
  return arr;
}

console.log(getKey(veg));
```

Using method **filter**

```js
var veg = {"mushrooms": 30, "peppers": 60, "meatballs": 1, "chicken": 
2, "olives": 4}


function filterItems(arr) {
  return Object.keys(arr).filter(function(el) {
      return arr[el] > 5;
  })
}

console.log(filterItems(veg));
```

```js
var veg = {"mushrooms": 30, "peppers": 60, "meatballs": 1, "chicken": 
2, "olives": 4}

function filterItems(arr) {
  return Object.keys(arr).filter(el => arr[el] > 5);
}

console.log(filterItems(veg));
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, the result is giving me the indices. It should return ["mushroom", "pepper"] not  [ '0', '1' ]

Comment: @Юрий Светлов Thank you for this solutions. Still helps even pass 3 years.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `filter` and `map` with `Object.entries`:

```js
var veg = {
  "mushroom": 30,
  "pepper": 60,
  "corn": 1,
  "carrot": 2,
  "pumpkin": 4
};
var keys = Object.entries(veg).filter(([, v]) => v > 5).map(([k]) => k);
console.log(keys);
```

Answer (score 1):

Object.getOwnPropertyNames will return an array of the properties on an object, filter returns an array where the items from the array passed into the input function return true, in this case greater than 5.

```js
var veg = {"mushroom": 30, "pepper": 60, "corn": 1, "carrot": 2, "pumpkin": 4};

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(veg).filter(prop => veg[prop] > 5));
```

Comment: Is there a reason you opted for `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` instead of `Object.keys()` as in the OP?

Comment: Does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `for-in` loop to iterate over the object:

```js
const veg = {"mushroom": 30, "pepper": 60, "corn": 1, "carrot": 2, "pumpkin": 4};

const out = [];

for (let key in veg) {
  if (veg[key] > 5) out.push(key);
}

console.log(out);
```